# Is it possible to use pure CSS to control the color of each area in the highchart polar chart (series.type=column)?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

What I expect:

[image: demo]

Code and demo:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    polar: true
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Also known as Radar Chart'
  },

  pane: {
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360
  },

  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 45,
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    labels: {
      format: '{value}°'
    }
  },

  yAxis: {
    min: 0
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: 0,
      pointInterval: 45
    },
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0
    }
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Column',
    data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    pointPlacement: 'between'
  }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 660px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <p class="highcharts-description">
    A polar chart showing different series types on a radial axis. Polar
    charts, also known as a radar charts, are often used to compare
    multivariate data sets. A polar chart in Highcharts is simply a
    cartesian chart where the X axis is wrapped around the perimeter. It
    can render common cartesian series types like line, column, area or
    arearange.
  </p>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    polar: true
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Also known as Radar Chart'
  },

  pane: {
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360
  },

  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 45,
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    labels: {
      format: '{value}°'
    }
  },

  yAxis: {
    min: 0
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: 0,
      pointInterval: 45
    },
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0
    }
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Column',
    data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    pointPlacement: 'between'
  }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 660px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}

/*You can change the color using this selector*/
.highcharts-series-group path{
  fill: red !important;
}

.highcharts-series-group path:hover{
  opacity: 0.6
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <p class="highcharts-description">
    A polar chart showing different series types on a radial axis. Polar
    charts, also known as a radar charts, are often used to compare
    multivariate data sets. A polar chart in Highcharts is simply a
    cartesian chart where the X axis is wrapped around the perimeter. It
    can render common cartesian series types like line, column, area or
    arearange.
  </p>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to enable the `colorByPoint` option and define `colors` array:

```
  colors: ['#2f7ed8', '#0d233a', '#8bbc21', '#910000', '#1aadce', '#492970', '#f28f43', '#77a1e5', '#c42525', '#a6c96a'],
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      ...
      colorByPoint: true
    }
  },
  ...
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5h09mwy2/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.colorByPoint

---

If you need to do that by CSS only, you can use:

```
.highcharts-series-0 path:nth-child(1) {
  fill: red;
}

.highcharts-series-0 path:nth-child(2) {
  fill: orange;
}

.highcharts-series-0 path:nth-child(3) {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8cmv2edz/